# Why is the leftmost subset of a key not being used to optimise this ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb

Server version:

```
[root@cat best]# /usr/libexec/mysqld --version
/usr/libexec/mysqld  Ver 5.1.47 for redhat-linux-gnu on i386 (Source distribution)
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `Log` (
    `EntryId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `EntryTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    `Severity` ENUM(
        'LOG_LEVEL_CRITICAL',
        'LOG_LEVEL_ERROR',
        'LOG_LEVEL_WARNING',
        'LOG_LEVEL_NOTICE',
        'LOG_LEVEL_INFO',
        'LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG'
    ) NOT NULL,

    `User` TEXT,
    `Text` TEXT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(`EntryId`),
    KEY `TimeId` (`EntryTime`,`EntryId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB COMMENT="Log of server activity";
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
   `EntryId`,
   `EntryTime`, -- or, ideally: UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`EntryTime`) AS `EntryTime_UnixTS`
   `Severity`,
   `User`,
   `Text`
FROM `Log` 
ORDER BY `EntryTime` DESC, `EntryId` DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

According to the execution plan (and observation), the index is not being used:

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE       Log    ALL   \N             \N   \N       \N   720   Using filesort
```

I've tried re-organising it a few ways with little success but, more than anything, would like to understand why this simple approach is failing. My understanding was that a left-most subset of any key can be used to optimise an `ORDER BY` operation.

Is my index wrong? Can I optimise the query?

Please note that I will also want to conditionally add, e.g.

```
WHERE `Severity` <= 'LOG_LEVEL_WARNING'
```

though I'd like to get the basic version working first if this makes the solution very different.

[Reproduced on SQLFiddle under MySQL 5.5.32.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cf700/3)

Comment: You are using a function call on that column (UNIX_TIMESTAMP) which makes indexes useless. They can only be used on non-computed columns

Comment: @juergend: Yet, [removing it, the problem persists](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cf700/3). I have abstracted it out the question to be clearer. Thanks

Comment: (Still, I'm surprised by what you say - the index on `EntryTime` can't be used to speed up the `ORDER` and `LIMIT`, before the function is applied to the resulting data?)

Comment: The order by is done by the computed column since you gave that one the same name as the original column name which makes it a bit confusing.

Comment: @juergend: Oh, right ok - so if I selected `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(EntryTime) AS TransformedEntryTime` and ordered by `EntryTime` then that would be "as able" to use the index? Again, not that that helps me for _this_ problem, but I guess it's the next one I'll face ;)

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: BTW it uses the index when forced: `... FROM Log FORCE INDEX (timeid) ORDER BY ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you index includes the primary key in it. and since it is InnoDB, by default the PK is ancluded in all other indexes as the left-most field. i.e. the index in this case is (EntryId, EntryTime, EntryId).

The solution is to have this index only on (EntryTime):

```
alter table Log drop index TimeId;
alter table Log add index TimeId(EntryTime);
explain SELECT     `EntryId`,    `EntryTime`,     `Severity`,    `User`,    `Text` FROM `Log`  ORDER BY `EntryTime` DESC, `EntryId` DESC LIMIT 0, 20;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Log   | index | NULL          | TimeId | 4       | NULL |   20 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-------+
```

HTH

Comment: Yeah, that does help, thanks! It doesn't help that the `possible_keys` wasn't even being populated on a small dataset, leading me to believe that a key just on `EntryTime` didn't work either when I randomly tried it early on. `FORCE INDEX` reveals that the index can be used, and now that I've tested your solution verbatim on my large dataset I can confirm that it works (without `FORCE INDEX`). Unfortunately, adding the range condition on `Severity` breaks it no matter what I do, but I think I can see why that is and I need to think about that new problem some more.