# How can I filter by one column whilst sorting by another?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `Log` (
    `EntryId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `EntryTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    `Severity` ENUM(
        'LOG_LEVEL_CRITICAL',
        'LOG_LEVEL_ERROR',
        'LOG_LEVEL_WARNING',
        'LOG_LEVEL_NOTICE',
        'LOG_LEVEL_INFO',
        'LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG'
    ) NOT NULL,

    `User` TEXT,
    `Text` TEXT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(`EntryId`),
    KEY `EntryTime` (`EntryTime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB COMMENT="Log of server activity";
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
   `EntryId`,
   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`EntryTime`) AS `EntryTime_UnixTS`
   `Severity`,
   `User`,
   `Text`
FROM `Log` 
ORDER BY `EntryTime` DESC, `EntryId` DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

According to observation, and to the execution plan (though this requires `FORCE INDEX` on small datasets!), the index is being used as desired:

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key        key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE       Log    index \N             EntryTime  4        \N   20
```

Now I want to add a range condition:

```
WHERE `Severity` <= 'LOG_LEVEL_WARNING'
```

but I can't figure out how to choose a key such that this simple query can still use an index whilst sorting on one column and filtering on another. The more I think about it, the more my weak SQL intuition suggests that it's not even possible with the query in its current form, not least because the condition is on a *range*.

How would you approach this?

Comment: What about creating a new index on `Severity,EntryTime,EntryId` ?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d3397/1

Comment: @juergend: That `WHERE` will be slow, won't it? Your new severity index isn't being used

Comment: @OscarPérez: Huh, that seems to work. I'm confused as to how, especially because of what I learnt in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26876041/560648)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you need to create an index that includes the three required fields:

```
CREATE INDEX test_idx
          ON Log (Severity,EntryTime,EntryId);
```

Ther server will be able to use this index as it includes everything that is needed to execute the query.

Comment: I was told in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26876041/560648) that a trailing PK on an index was wrong. Why is that different here? It does seem to work but I can't conceptualise why that is :( I mean, with the range condition, it's going to have to do some sorting no matter what, right? So how come the result is so fast :/

Comment: I had never read that... is it really true? Did you found any official mysql pages stating this? As far as I know, using the index will help the server to locate all the records in a range inside of it in a faster (logarithmic?) way...

Comment: Yeah I suppose the index will help to a large degree even if the lookup cannot be made constant; that would explain it. As for the trailing PK thing, I don't know, it's what I was told and the solution given on that answer worked.